# CakePHP extending baked controllers

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I'm working on a pretty complex application, so for simplicity sake, I'll go with a "Movies" example.

If I use the console to bake a table "Movies" with view fields like release date, genre etc.. and I wanted to add to to the Movies table by extending the MoviesController to add actors to specific movies:

```
class ActorsControler extends MoviesController{

}
```

How would I go about doing this conventionally.. is there a best practice as far as CakePHP is concerned?  I'd like there to be separation between the Movies and Actors views, so I can present a list of movies and have an option to view actors of a selected movie separately.  I could do this procedurally however I was hoping I could just extend the MoviesController and add to the Movies table that way.  Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps I might be reading into your simplification too much, but do you want to extend the controller or form a relationship with it? Its sounds like you want a `Movies hasMany Actors` relationship.